# CustomTicks and Mathematica 13.0

Tags: plotting, ticks, version-13

Here is the code, which uses the [CustomTicks](https://github.com/mark-caprio/CustomTicks) package:

```
<< CustomTicks`

Plot[
     {Log10[Cosh[x]], Log10[Sinh[x]]}, {x, 0, 10},
     PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 4}, {-0.5, 2.5}},
     FrameTicks -> {{LogTicks, None}, {LinTicks, None}},
     Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 72*3
     ]

Plot[
     x, {x, 0, 10},
     FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks, None}, {LinTicks, None}},
     Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 72*3
     ]
```

For Mathematica 12.3 these are the results (which are the expected ones):

[image]

For Mathematica 13.0 the results are:

[image]

Does someone knows what is happening with LinTicks and if there is a workaround?

I essentially use CustomTicks to control the ticks length. If you have other suggestions they are welcome. I find the native Mathematica control for the tick marks very cumbersome.

Comment: Would you want to use the undocumented ticks functions buried in the `Charting` context? I think that is the right context, I’m trying to remember it off hand. But if you are interested, I (& others) can try to find some useful links for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you might contact the developer of the package you link to, and ask them when to expect they will update the package for V13 (and, possibly, notify them of this issue).

Comment: @CATrevillian, thanks. I opened an issue in github. Anyway, I am open to other approaches. If you can provide the information on that undocumented ticks that you mention, it would be welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CustomTicks](https://github.com/mark-caprio/CustomTicks) package was just updated (version 2.1.2) and it is now working with Mathematica 13.0.

I posted an issue in github and the developer promptly generated a new version with the correction. Thanks!

Anyway, if someone knows about easy alternative ways for changing the tick marks length, they are welcome. CustomTicks is working now, but it is good to know about alternatives.

**Example**: Here is a usage example of CustomTicks v2.1.2 within Mathematica 13.0

```
<< CustomTicks`

SetOptions[LinTicks,
  MajorTickLength -> {0.020, 0},
  MinorTickLength -> {0.010, 0},
  MajorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.001], 
  MinorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.001]
];

frameticksoptions = {
  {LinTicks, StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}, 
  {LinTicks, StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}
};

Plot[{x , x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, 
  Frame -> True
]

Plot[{x , x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> frameticksoptions
]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! It helps to know the developer is so very quick. This encourages me to try to use this package, then...can you, please, clarify if you are successful using the same call that you show having had the original issue with?

Comment: @CATrevillian, yes, I've tested it in v 13 using the same call. To be clear, and to add a useful CustomTicks setup, I just edited the answer above to insert an example.